# Three-Address-Code (TAC) and Conjunction/Disjunction

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-language, tac

I want to translate a conjunction (same for disjunction) to TAC.

```
int a;
int b;

bool c = a > 1 && b < 5;
```

The post [how-to-represent-binary-logical-in-three-address-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779746/how-to-represent-binary-logical-in-three-address-code) answers the first half of my question. But it doesn't answer, how the result shall be handled. My solution would be as following:

```
    if a <= 1 goto L1
    _t1 = b < 5
    goto L2
L1: _t1 = 0
L2: c = _t1
```

The problem is, that I read (because of later optimization issues), temporaries shall be restricted to basic blocks.
My solution would violate this rule.

Is this a problem?
How can I create TAC without this violation?

*Note:*
I want to handle the AST-branches independent of one another.
So that the result-assignment is handled after the logical operation and therefor just assigning the results directly to `c` is not viable.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use logical operators outside of conditions?
If yes, then you can do:

```
_t0 = b < 5
_t1 = a > 1
c = _t0 & _t1
```

Otherwise, if you are not allowed to use logical operators outside conditions:

```
    if a <= 1 goto False
    if b > 5 goto False
    c = 1
    goto True
False:
    c = 0
True:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can not evaluate the sub-terms beforhand. This would go against lacy evaluation (e.g. `x != null && x.count() > 3`). The other solution would go against the way I generate code. Which is by traversing the AST via tree-walker. When I generate the code for the `and`part, I do not kow what is done with the solution yet (used in `if`, or `assignment`, or part of another expression).

Comment: I will accept this answer, because I can't find another solution. Passing additional information down the AST it is. Thus, I will handle logigal `and` and `or` differently than "normal" binary operations (which only have one temporary variable as result).